# Expand a dict key with dot as another dict

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a dictionary looks like

```
var p = {
     'name' : "John",
     'personal.phone' : "123456",
     'office.phone.number' : "321654",
     'office.phone.extn': "4"
}
```

I want to convert the dict with doted keys expanded like

```
{
     'name' : "John",
     'personal' : {
                       'phone' : "123456",
                  }
     'office' :   {
                        'phone' : { 
                                      number : "321654",
                                      extn : "4" 
                                  }
}
```

A function I wrote for expanding a single key. but its not exiting the loop

```
function expdictkey(str,v) {
    str = str.split(".").reverse();
    var p = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        p[str[i]] = p
        console.log(p)
    }
    return p;
}
```

expdictkey("phone.number.extn","4")

I am getting values from a from in the form of first dict, I want to convert it like second dict and put it in a model and save it. using backbone.js, and django rest server. in server the model is in the form of second dict.

Comment: What `backbone.js` does here?

Comment: i am getting values from a from in the form of first dict, I want to convert it and put it in a model and save it.  using backbonejs, and django rest server. in server the model is in the form of second dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var p = {
  'name': "John",
  'personal.phone': "123456",
  'office.phone.number': "321654",
  'office.phone.extn': "4"
}




function unwrap() {
  var obj = {};
  for (var index in p) {
    var keys = index.split('.');
    var value = p[index];
    var ref = obj;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      var key = keys[i];
      if (keys.length - 1 === i) {
        ref[key] = value;
      } else {
        if (ref[key] === undefined) {
          ref[key] = {}
        }
        ref = ref[key]
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

unwrap(p);
```

Comment: You really should add `if(p.hasOwnProperty(index))` to protect the loop.

Comment: I don't think so, instead don't add prototypes to iterable object.

Comment: Every object has a prototype in JavaScript whether you like it or not. It may be frowned upon to extend Object.prototype, but even worse to write code that can be broken so easily.

Comment: I think this is a preference. I see what you are saying, especially if you are using a lot of foreign code. But honestly, just don't extend iterable objects in javascript.